# Inclusion of ideals in \mathbb{C}[x,y]

Tags: maximal-and-prime-ideals

I have to answer to questions. I try to give the answer myself and would appreciate if you told me if they are correct.

In the ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, do the following inclusions of ideals hold?

1. $(x-1,y-2)\subset(y^2-4x)$
2. $(y^2-4x)\subset(x-1,y-2)$

I start with 2.: Yes, this inclusion holds, since the ideal $m:=(x-1,y-2)$ is a maximal ideal in the ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. Therefore, the ideal $(y^2-4x)$ is contained in $m$ since $y^2-4x$ vanishes for $x=1$ and $y=2$.

Now 1.: I would say that the inclusion does not hold. If this was the case, then we would have $x-1=(y^2-4x)\cdot p(x,y)$ for some polynomial $p(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ (same reasoning for $y-2$). But there does not exist such a $p(x,y)$ and we have a contradiction.

An additional question with regard to 1.: How do I prove that $m$ is indeed maximal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: the residue ring is a field, thus the ideal is maximal.

Comment: rbarc: thank you! I wasn't clear enough in my additional question. I wanted to know why $m=\mathrm{ker}(\varphi)$, where $\varphi$ is the evaluation homomorphism

Comment: Does somebody have a hint to the solution I proposed?